# File in /usr/local/bin can't be seen by some users

Tags: linux, centos, users

I'm installing Wordpress CLI from the official instructions, logged in as a user with sudo permissions on a VPS, Centos Server with cloud linux:

Download the WP-CLI tool from Github with the following command:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
```

Confirm that it has downloaded successfully with this command:

```
$ php wp-cli.phar --info
```

Now you need to set wp-cli.phar to be an executable file. Type:

```
$ chmod +x wp-cli.phar
```

To finalize the installation, move WP-CLI into its final location:

```
$ sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
```

All worked well, wp-cli works from there.
But when I log out and back in as a different user, I get `wp: command not found`
If I do `cd /usr/local/bin` then `ls` I can see some files but not wp. What do I need to do so this user can see and use wp?

UPDATE:
Having run `cat /etc/passwd` as suggested, here is the output:

```
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
uucp:x:10:14:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
gopher:x:13:30:gopher:/var/gopher:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
vcsa:x:69:69:virtual console memory owner:/dev:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
named:x:25:25:Named:/var/named:/sbin/nologin
dovecot:x:97:97:dovecot:/usr/libexec/dovecot:/sbin/nologin
nscd:x:28:28:NSCD Daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
postfix:x:89:89::/var/spool/postfix:/sbin/nologin
mailman:x:32006:32006
::/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell
mailnull:x:47:47:Exim:/var/spool/mqueue:/bin/false
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
mysql:x:498:499:MySQL server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/bash 
cpaneleximfilter:x:32007:32009::/var/cpanel/userhomes/cpaneleximfilter:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell
```

Comment: Is it still there when you come back as the original user? There is no selective listing of contents of a directory, permissions-wise, so my guess is maybe one of your users really is in a chroot jail or similar, which means they might not have the same `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Yes still there, there’s lots more files there when logged in as the user that installed it. Drush is in there too and that’s visible to all users. How would I check the jail suggestion?

Comment: if you cat /etc/passwd to check on the other user, is there anything weird about the user that you are having issues with? like Ulrich said, do you see them in a jail? with a different shell?  what are the permissions for that wp file you're trying to access?

Comment: I did cat etc/passwd, not sure what I'm looking for, output's too long for a comment, I'll edit the question with that added, permissions are -rwxrwxr-x

Answer (score 1):

OK, looks like Ulrich was on the right track with a jail, it was *cagefs* - I needed to add `/usr/local/bin/wp` to *binutils.cfg* - found the answer here: https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/cloudlinux/how-to-add-commands-to-cagefs-users